# FFMPEG... Command not found

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I used to use ffmpeg to record m3u8 to ts with this:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://website.com/video.m3u8” -c copy video.ts
```

But ever since I reinstalled my Mac OS and reinstalled ffmpeg, this is all I get...

```
[2] 13658
[3] 13659
[4] 13660
[5] 13661
[6] 13662
[7] 13663
[8] 13664
[9] 13665
[10] 13666
[11] 13667
[12] 13668
-bash: -c: command not found
[3]   Done                    ct=c
[4]   Done                    cid=d75941e582c04e68bb32d3190283d3ae
[5]   Done                    iph=734d88352254c6f5e0af6640fea47abcdc5c1aba75569cc8e0e35968a93e7c8e
[6]   Done                    rays=jihgfedcb
[7]   Done                    euid=01B45906-9A14-45F9-BFFD-7867467502A4_007_1_001_live_03-06-00_NA
[8]   Done                    cdn=ec
[9]   Done                    stgcfg=datg
[10]   Done                    pp2ip=0
[11]   Done                    delay=10800
[12]-  Done                    sig=73be1ff856a52b5522b9f12e495c91241a3017e8b80ce5fff18c18513330930a
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not really putting the URL in quotes, or the URL has a quote in it you are not escaping.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this means, what it implies, how you deduced it, and what steps the user needs to take to fix it?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.